# Python Decoding Uncode files with 'ÆØÅ'

Tags: python, unicode-string

I read in some data from a danish text file. But i can't seem to find a way to decode it.
The original text is "dør" but in the raw text file its stored as "d√∏r"

So i tried the obvious

```
InputData = "d√∏r"
Print InputData.decode('iso-8859-1')
```

sadly resulting in the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

UTF-8 gives the same error.
(using Python 2.6.5)

How can i decode this text so the printed message would be "dør"?

Comment: What version of python? Also you should decode as utf-8 if that is what it is.

Comment: Version 2 and utf-8 doesn't work.

Comment: 2 is not a version of python.

Comment: Your snippet may seem "obvious" to you, but actually you're making things even harder on yourself because now you have to deal with the Python script's encoding in addition to the encoding of your text file.

Comment: Your text isn't stored as "d√∏r". Decoding the bytes with some encoding results in those characters; the question is what the actual bytes are, and what encoding they're actually encoded with in your original file.

Comment: The text is stored as d√∏r (or dÃ¸r). The bytes are 64 C3 B8 72

Answer (score 0):

`C3 B8` is the UTF-8 encoding for "ø".  You need to read the file in UTF-8 encoding:

```
import codecs
codecs.open(myfile, encoding='utf-8')
```

The reason that you're getting a `UnicodeEncodeError` is that you're trying to *output* the text and Python doesn't know what encoding your terminal is in, so it defaults to `ascii`.  To fix this issue, use `sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)` or use the environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8"`.

Note that this will give you the text as `unicode` objects; if everything else in your program is `str` then you're going to run into compatibility issues.  Either convert everything to `unicode` or (probably easier) re-encode the file into Latin-1 using `ustr.encode('iso-8859-1')`, but be aware that this will break if anything is outside the Latin-1 codepage.  It might be easier to convert your program to use `str` in `utf-8` encoding internally.

Comment: tried the codec.open but got this error UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf8' in position 70

Comment: @user1095570 yes, you're going to have to be consistent in your use of `unicode` and `str`.

Comment: I was about to give this +1, until I read the last paragraph. Converting everything to Latin-1 just seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: tried this:

    `import codecs
    PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8"
    file = codecs.open('/temptex.txt', encoding='UTF-8')
    for line in file:
        print line`

on a text file with the following bytes:
    `C3 B8 (√∏ in string)`

that gives me following error:
    `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Apparently can't reply with code, here is my response: http://pastebin.com/KL7dL59D

Comment: @user1095570 PYTHONIOENCODING is an environment variable; you use it as `env PYTHONIOENCODING="utf-8" python myfile.py`.